# How to use socks proxy for commands in Terminal such as youtube-dl?

Tags: ssh, proxy, http-proxy, socks

I connect to a remote ssh server by running this command:

```
ssh -D 12345 bob@myserver.com
```

This creates a socks proxy that I can use with Firefox to bypass censorship in my country. However, I can't take advantage of it to in the command line.

Let's say my country blocks access to youtube. How can I use the ssh connection to run a command such as:

```
youtube-dl "youtube.com/watch?v=3XjwiV-6_CA"
```

Without being blocked by the government? How I can set a socks proxy for all terminal commands?

Comment: I found a temporary solution. I've used tsocks. Once installed, when the ssh connection is established, I launch the application I want with tsocks as follows: tsocks gnome-terminal

Comment: `tsocks youtube-dl ...` - tsocks is a clever application, commonly available in repositories, that uses `LD_PRELOAD` to force applications to route their traffic through a designated SOCKS connection (specify which in `~/.tsocks.conf`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Youtube-dl doesn't support a SOCKS proxy. There's a [feature request](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/402) for it, with links to a couple of working proposals.

Youtube-dl supports HTTP proxies out of the box. To benefit from this support, you'll need to run a proxy on `myserver.com`. Pretty much any lightweight proxy will do, for example [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/). The proxy only needs to listen to local connections (`Listen 127.0.0.1` in `tinyproxy.conf`). If the HTTP proxy is listening on port 8035 (`Port 8035`), run the following ssh command:

```
ssh -L 8035:localhost:8035 bob@myserver.com
```

and set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`:

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:8035/ https_proxy=http://localhost:8035/
youtube-dl youtube.com/watch?V=3XjwiV-6_CA
```

Comment: if they are going to use SSH then why do they need tinyproxy or vice versa? I use SSH tunnel and it works fine.

Comment: @Neutralizer SSH only relays from the local machine to the proxy machine. Something on the proxy machine needs to decode the HTTP request and figure out the IP address of the server machine. If the client supports SOCKS then SSH can do the job, but youtube-dl doesn't support SOCKS. If you're using the proxy for a specific server, you may be able to use SSH alone and tell it to forward directly to that server, but that only works if all the requests need to be forwarded to the same IP address and port.

Comment: For debugging it is nice to run the ssh command with `-v` and to skip the interactive session one can also add `-N`.

Comment: [SOCKS proxy support has been added to `youtube-dl` on 2016.05.10](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/402#issuecomment-218187016).

Answer (score 88):

```
ssh -D 8080 name@myserver.com
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080
youtube-dl "youtube.com/watch?V=3XjwiV-6_CA"
```

Comment: simple and works for me.

Comment: add `-N` to skip the interactive ssh session

Comment: How do I make applied to all protocol or general protocol such as UDP and TCP instead of only http and https?

Comment: i get `Unsupported scheme 'socks5'` error

Answer (score 15):

youtube-dl works well with proxychains on ubuntu.  Make sure ur tunneling via command line.

```
ssh -D 8081 ubuntu@yourSSHserver
```

next install proxychains on your localhost not the ssh server ur conncted to.

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

edit your proxychains config file

```
sudo nano /etc/proxychains.conf
```

edit the port number on the last line

```
socks4  127.0.0.1 8081
```

Note:I'm using proxychains on port 8081

then just add proxychains to the begining of the command when using youtube-dl

```
proxychains ./youtube-dl http://thesite.com/yourvideo.hmtl
```

Comment: proxychains is a cool tool

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Delegate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/SOCKS/),

It's a SOCKS server and/or client that can listen as HTTP proxy.

Download [latest](http://delegate.hpcc.jp/anonftp/DeleGate/bin/linux/latest/) version of delegate and extract it.

First run your ssh command:

```
ssh -D 9150 me@myserver.com
```

Then, run binary delegate file with these options to have a HTTP proxy as a SOCKS client:

```
$ ./dg9_9_13 -P8080 SERVER=http SOCKS=127.0.0.1:9150 ADMIN="local@localhost.com"
```

Then, run `youtube-dl` with `--proxy` option to connect to listened HTTP proxy:

```
$ youtube-dl -v --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VID
```

Answer (score 3):

Since [`youtube-dl` version 2016.05.10](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/402#issuecomment-218187016), you can use `--proxy` to specify SOCKS proxy, e.g.

```
youtube-dl --proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1/" -v 9bZkp7q19f0
```

> `--proxy URL` Use the specified HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS proxy. To enable experimental SOCKS proxy, specify a proper scheme. For example `socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/`.

Answer (score 0):

If Youtube videos are what you are after, you might want to try [`cclive`](http://cclive.sourceforge.net/), which seems to support proxies. And it can do other streaming sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [polipo](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/polipo) to create an http proxy and use your socks5 proxy as the parent proxy.

```
$ polipo socksParentProxy=127.0.0.1:12345 # change accordingly
Established listening socket on port 8123
```

Now, you can use `127.0.0.1:8123` as an http proxy with any command-line tool that supports it.