# Create Network Interface from SSH Tunnel

Tags: network-interface, ssh-tunneling, tap

To route your network traffic through SSH, most people would tell you to pass the `-D` option to create a SOCKS proxy on localhost that you can configure your applications to use.

However, a simple proxy isn't the most practical solution for me. Is there any way to access a SSH tunnel as it's own interface, perhaps with TUN/TAP?

I'm using Linux.

Comment: Yes, there is. Look up `Tunnel` and `TunnelDevice` in the `ssh_config(5)` manpage and the `-w` option in the `ssh(1)`. I won't make this an answer because it's a long time I've tried that, and I've only used for testing, and I don't know how good it works. Anyway, you'll have to set the owner of the tun/tap devices with eg. `tunctl(8)` if you're to use that as a regular user.

Comment: @mosvy It works great, but has some caveats, use it infrequently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using OpenSSH in Linux, tunnels can be created over SSH using either TUN or TAP interfaces, as long as proper routing is setup and ip forwarding where appropriate.

For creating a TUN tunnel, will leave here a practical script, from [Ip Tunnel Over Ssh With Tun](http://www.marcfargas.com/posts/ip-tunnel-over-ssh-with-tun/) ; the script assumes you are running as root.

> Add “PermitTunnel yes” to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>   Now, on the client it’s as easy as to run ssh with some parameters, my script for launching it is:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> HOST=REMOTE_PARTY_ADDRESS
> HOST_PORT=22
> TUN_LOCAL=0   # tun device number here.
> TUN_REMOTE=0  # tun device number there
> IP_LOCAL=192.168.111.2 # IP Address for tun here
> IP_REMOTE=192.168.111.1 # IP Address for tun there.
> IP_MASK=30 # Mask of the ips above.
> NET_REMOTE=192.168.0.0/16 # Network on the other side of the tunnel
> NET_LOCAL=192.168.8.0/24  # Network on this side of the tunnel
>
> echo "Starting VPN tunnel ..." 
> modprobe tun
> ssh -w ${TUN_LOCAL}:${TUN_REMOTE} -f ${HOST} -p ${HOST_PORT} "\
> ip addr add ${IP_REMOTE}/${IP_MASK} dev tun${TUN_REMOTE} \
> && ip link set tun${TUN_REMOTE} up \
> && ip route add ${NET_LOCAL} via ${IP_LOCAL} \
> && true"
> sleep 3
> ip addr add ${IP_LOCAL}/${IP_MASK} dev tun${TUN_LOCAL}
> ip link set tun${TUN_LOCAL} up
> ip route add ${NET_REMOTE} via ${IP_REMOTE}
> echo "... done."
> ```

If you want to access/tunnel a network instead of a single machine, you also have to activate ip forwarding, as in:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

You also have a script at https://github.com/trustedsec/tap/blob/master/scripts/ssh-tunnel.sh for creating an OpenSSH tunnel over a TAP interface.

Comment: I cannot recall whether net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0 has to be set or not.

Comment: So root access is required?

Comment: @KenSharp Several operations there need root.