# Create Network Interface with SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, routing, vpn, ssh-tunneling

My question has already been asked with this exact title, however since new users brilliantly cannot ask further questions in the comment section because of reputation the only viable option that I saw was creating another question, sorry for that. Here is a link for the original question: [Create Network Interface from SSH Tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525217/create-network-interface-from-ssh-tunnel)

I'm also connecting to a remote server through ssh using a dynamic port and creating a socks proxy just like in the example. With this method, some programs still ignore proxy settings and environment variables so after some research, funneling everything to a proper tunnel adapter seems to be the solution.
I just learned about tunnels and already committed the mistake of looping my new tunnel through the ssh connection (which loops and kills all connections, oops lol)

The answer to the original question linked above, the script to set up a tunnel using the ssh connection, seems to be the solution I'm looking for.

However due to my inexperience with tunnels and connection, I don't seem to fully understand how to properly populate said script (TUN_LOCAL, TUN_REMOTE, etc), how would one properly populate such script?
I need to login with my username and password into the remote machine when creating the ssh tunnel originally, do I need to open my ssh tunnel and THEN open the script or do I need to include my username and password into the script somehow?
Answers with examples (I'm slow sorry) would be really appreciated! Thank you!